# When was the first strap-on booster used in spaceflight?

Tags: launch, history, terminology, booster, spaceflight-firsts

The first use of the term "strap-on" in Google Ngram viewer is in 1930 and presumably that wasn't about a booster being attached to a rocket for additional thrust at lift-off.

When was a strap-on booster first used in spaceflight; beyond Karman, suborbital is allowed.

Was it in the late 1980's when the term had a sudden rise in popularity?

[image: strap-on Ngram]

Comment: Maybe you should also take a look at similar terms, such as "side booster"?

Comment: @EverydayAstronaut it's a visual aid to get the ball rolling. Ngram is available to everyone at https://books.google.com/ngrams

Comment: @uhoh I don't think that's an accurate ngram, the words in question are used in many applications. It would look more along the lines of [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=solidstate&year_start=1800&year_end=2008) or [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spaceflight&year_start=1800&year_end=2008) if it were accurate and only referencing space-flight.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I never said it applied only to spaceflight. Once again, [it's a visual aid to get the ball rolling.](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/34885/when-was-the-first-strap-on-booster-used-in-spaceflight?noredirect=1#comment109210_34885) I thought it was pretty obvious that since it starts in 1930 it included other usages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Boosters were in use by [21 August 1957](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-7_Semyorka), the first successful suborbital launch of the R-7.

Definition of 'booster':

> A booster rocket (or engine) is either the first stage of a multistage launch vehicle, or else a shorter-burning rocket used in parallel with longer-burning sustainer rockets to augment the space vehicle's takeoff thrust and payload capability.

The term "Strap-on booster" is somewhat ambiguous. Literally, it means the booster is attached to the rocket via straps. I don't know any boosters that are attached like that: they are usually attached via fittings that are part of the booster's structure, and not a separate band that runs around the booster's body.

Some people use "strap-on booster" as a synonym for "booster", but that's pointless.

Strap-on boosters are, in my opinion, a subclass: this refers to [boosters that are optional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booster_(rocketry)#Strap-on), i.e. the core stage can be launched either without or with boosters.

Some notable rockets that used strap-on boosters:

- Titan 3, first launch of a [Titan 3C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_IIIC) with boosters was in 1965.
- [Ariane 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_3), first launch in 1984.
- [Delta 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_II), first launch 1989.

From [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_orbital_launch_systems), I'd say the Titan 3 is the first operational rocket to use strap-on boosters.

Comment: Wikipedia does use the term strap-on in several R-7 related pages.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Wikipedia article on the Titan IIIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_IIIC) the first flight of that vehicle was on 1965 June 18. Prior to that, on [1964 August 19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_D) a successful flight of a rocket variously known as the "Thrust Augmented Delta" (TAD) or "Delta D" or "Thor-Delta D" ushered in operational use of strap-ons for US launch systems. The TAD flew again successfully on 1965 April 6.

After that the success with the TAD prompted the highly successful Delta series of medium-lift launchers. [This article](http://www.astronautix.com/d/delta.html) discusses the development from the single-engine Thor IRBM to the Delta series. Concerning the adoption of thrust augmenters,

> After the Sputnik shock, all available assets were pressed into
>   service. Thor was developed into a workhorse for the space program.
>   The Able stage developed for the Vanguard project was mated to the
>   Thor. A fundamental problem was that the thrust to weight ratio of the
>   basic vehicle left little margin for growth or larger upper stages.
>   This was solved by using Castor solid rockets strapped to the base of
>   the vehicle to increase the lift-off thrust. Almost by accident rather
>   than design, Thor developed into the Delta, the standard American
>   medium-lift launcher, continually evolving through the use of more and
>   larger strap-on boosters, a cylindrical and stretched core, and
>   enlarged upper stages.

Comment: Thanks! Some possibly related JATO material here https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34020/12102 ?

Answer (score 3):

Moving further into the past (since you allowed suborbital flights, and this vehicle has a stated apogee of [240 miles](http://www.astronautix.com/s/shotput.html), well above the *line-whose-name-shall-not-be-spoken*) there is the Sergeant-Delta aka Shotput.

> on October 28, 1959, NASA launched a  30-m (100-ft) inflatable sphere
> into a suborbital trajectory from Wallops Island as part of Project
> Shotput. Project Shotput used a  Sergeant-Delta launch vehicle to test
> payloads for the Echo passive communications satellite project.
>
> ..................
>
> Sergeant-Delta: A large rocket used by NASA in Project Shotput in
> preparation for launching the Echo satellites. Consisted of a Sergeant
> plus 2 strapped-on Recruits plus a  Delta X-248 second stage.

Source [NASA Sounding Rockets](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4401.pdf)

[image]

[Image source](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_lau_det/shotput.htm)

Comment: My head is spinning! [Help me understand what Farside, a ten "stage" rockoon looked like? How was it configured?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34914/12102)

Comment: I don't know the proper configuration-agnostic term for a propulsive component of a stack of unspecified configuration in this case, so I used stage, then added quotes to it.

Comment: I'm kind of sad, a 10 stager would have been awesome.  This Farside's pretty cool though, total burn time < 8 seconds and it goes to 2000 miles.  That's some savage acceleration.

Comment: yes, my head continues to spin...