# Rocket staging by use of strap on Boosters

Tags: rockets, design-alternative, booster, stages

Will it be advantageous to have multiple (say-3) stages of a rocket, arranged in a "strap-on" type SRBs' assembly, geometrically well distributed around the circumference w.r.t. their numbers in each "stage" (though their ignition/firing will be sequential i.e. in series) - instead of arranging them one over the other? Will such an arrangement pose any problems in "steering" of the rocket (presuming SRBs do not have a gimbled nozzle)

Comment: Different but related questions: [Help me understand what Farside, a ten “stage” rockoon looked like? How was it configured?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34914/12102) and [Where is Farside's 4th stage?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36260/12102) Have a look at the "third" and "fourth" stages!

Comment: SRBs can have gimbaled nozzles, STS did.

Answer (score 2):

> Will it be advantageous to have multiple (say-3) stages of a rocket, arranged in a "strap-on" type SRBs' assembly, geometrically well distributed around the circumference

There's a small *dis*advantage; the aerodynamic cross-section of such a rocket is larger than a longitudinally staged rocket, so it loses more energy to air resistance.

Side-mounted liquid-fueled boosters do offer the possibility of propellant cross-feed, using the fuel stored in the outer boosters to fill the inner ones during concurrent burns, but there's no advantage in sequential burns.

> Will such an arrangement pose any problems in "steering" of the rocket (presuming SRBs do not have a gimbled nozzle)

You need some sort of steering method; [modern SRBs on large launchers, as Organic Marble points out, usually do have gimbaled nozzles](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14992/195). Moving fins or secondary steerable thrusters are the other common options, but gimbaled nozzles are generally the most efficient solution.

The more compact arrangement you describe requires somewhat more sideways thrust force (from gimbals, fins, or thrusters) to turn the booster in flight -- another slight disadvantage.

Comment: Also probably a bigger launch pad for the larger diameter vehicle.

Comment: Some of this may be helpful for examples: [Is it unusual to vector the thrust from an SRB?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14992) and [How does a single SRB control attitude?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20755)

Comment: @Russel Borogove, Organic Marble and Uhoh. Thanks. I want to "accept" the answers and appreciate the same, but could not find the "grey" button which (as someone had pointed out earlier) I need to press for this. Thanks anyway.